# Should I use list comprehensions instead of a normal for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, list-comprehension

**Problem**

An enterprise wants to make an app that helps sticker collectors keep track of what cards they've got, stick figures come in pack of many stickers and sometimes the collector gets repeated cards, and the most important ones are the stickers that are considered rare.

**Entry**

The first line has X int numbers indicating the bought stickers, the second line has Y int numbers referring to the rare stickers.

**Exit**

Only one line containing the number of remaining stick figures.

**Solution**

The for loop approach:

```
bought_stickers = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
rare_stickers = [int(i) for i in input().split()]

rare_stickers_left = len(rare_stickers)

for i in rare_stickers:
    if i in bought_stickers:
        rare_stickers_left -= 1

print(rare_stickers_left)
```

The list comprehension approach:

```
bought_stickers = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
rare_stickers = [int(i) for i in input().split()]

rare_stickers_left = [i for i in rare_stickers if i not in bought_stickers]
print(len(rare_stickers_left))
```

My question is, which solution is the best considering, readability, effectiveness and all?

Also, which is better for coding olimpiads?

Comment: List comprehension is the more elegant, "pythonic" way.

Comment: Oh, ok thx, I'll use it instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither: the Pythonic way is simply to count occurrences, not to make a new list of large objects.

```
rare_stickers_left = sum(i not in bought_stickers for i in rare_stickers)
```

This simply adds up all the `True` results (taken as `1`).

Another possibility is to make sets and take the set difference:

```
rare_stickers_left = len(set(rare_stickers) - set(bought_stickers))
```

However, this has the overhead of making three sets and calling `len` on the temporary one.

Comment: @HeapOverflow Thanks; fixed

Answer (score 1):

The list comprehension is:

- More concise
- More "Pythonic"
- More efficient (avoids unnecessary variable lookups)
- Simpler, so less chance for bugs
- etc.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the first 2 `for loops` here:

```
bought_stickers = input().split()
rare_stickers = input().split() 
rare_stickers_left = [int(i) for i in rare_stickers if i not in bought_stickers]
print(len(rare_stickers_left))
```

Comment: Thx for the tip! The only problem is that this way the list is made of string values